# How to write data to seperate columns in csv file

Tags: java, excel, oracle, csv

Hi so I wanted to write a web app that accepts excel file then converts it to csv file and uploads it to database, make some sql queries on this data and send an output to the user. I have encountered a problem in Mac it works perfectly fine but on windows it throws an exception. The exception being thrown is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900. I have checked the SQL query and it should work and besides it works perfectly fine on my mac. So I thought the problem might be in my csv file. On mac it writes the data that goes from excel to csv in different columns(cells) but when I open my csv file using excel it writes everything to one cell. So I am so confused. Can someone help me with this please? 
Here is my code:

```
package dto;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import com.csvreader.CsvWriter;

import servlets.Serv1;


public class Converter {
public final String COMA_DELIMITER=" ,";
String newname;
public File converting(File file, String p){
    Path path=Paths.get(file.getName());

    String filename=path.getFileName().toString();
    String extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, filename.length());
    if(extension.equals("csv"))
        return file;
    else if(extension.equals("xls")||extension.equals("xlsx")){
        try{
        newname=p+File.separator+filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf("."))+".csv";
        CsvWriter csvOutput=new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(newname,true), ',');
        System.out.println("I am delimiter "+csvOutput.getDelimiter());
        Workbook wb;
        if(extension.equals("xls")){
            wb=new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
        }
        else{
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
        }
        Sheet s=wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row = null;
        int j=0;
        Integer val;
        for(int i=0; i<s.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++){
            row=s.getRow(i);
            Cell c=row.getCell(j);
            if(c.getCellType()!=Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                continue;
            else{

                val=(int) c.getNumericCellValue();
                csvOutput.write(Integer.toString(val));
                //csvOutput.endRecord();
                //csvOutput.write(String.valueOf((i+1)));
                //csvOutput.endRecord();
                }
            csvOutput.write(String.valueOf((i+1)));
            csvOutput.endRecord();

        }
        csvOutput.close();
        wb.close();     
        return new File(newname);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }       
    }
    return null;            
}
public boolean insertIntoDb(File f){
    if(f==null)
        return false;
    else{
    String path=f.getAbsolutePath();
    Connection conn=null;
    Statement stmt=null;
    try{
        //System.out.println("Hello 1");
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        //System.out.println("Hello 2");

        conn=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@adress:orcl","almit","password");
        //System.out.println("Hello 3");

        stmt=conn.createStatement();
        //System.out.println("Hello 4");

        /*
         * query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '"+filename+"' INTO TABLE testtable  FIELDS
         * TERMINATED BY ',' (text,price)";
         */
        String select1="truncate table almit.TEMP_FOR_WORK";
        //System.out.println("Hello 5");
        stmt.execute(select1);
        //System.out.println("Hello");
        String select="LOAD DATA local INFILE '"+path+"' INTO TABLE TEMP_FOR_WORK FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
        //System.out.println(select);
        stmt.executeUpdate(select);     
        //System.out.println("Hello");

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }finally{
        try{
            if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
            if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
    return true;
}
```

}

I tried other ways to do it but they all output to one column. The result that I get is |colomun1|
       |customernumber, id|
the result I want to get |column 1|column2|
                         |customern|id|

Is it possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue could be this:

LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"

This is true in Mac (which is a Unix machine), however in Windows, lines are terminated by "\r\n".

In my opinion, instead of performing this conversion to CSV, you could extract the XML data from the XSL file and do a parsing of the XML document and insert the nodes. Could be a little bit more work, but it will make your application platform independent.

Good luck.

Comment: It should be enough to set proper record delimiter: `csvOutput.setRecordDelimiter('\n');`

Comment: Yeah, that is true as well.